# Querying Customer Saved Searches in Shopify Python API

Tags: python, rest, shopify

I'm trying to get all customers who abandoned their order last week.

I was able to achieved it through the [REST API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customersavedsearch#other-2019-07), however, I wonder how to achieve the same thing via Shopify Python API.

Here's the code I tried in Postman:

```
https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/customer_saved_searches/{customer_saved_search_id}/customers.json?limit=250
```

Also, it seems like there's a 250 results limit in the REST API, is there a way to exceed it?

Answer (score 0):

The Python SDK is a bit of afterthought of Shopify. Sadly.

Regarding the paging on th REST request. Just add the query parameter `...?page=2` at the end of your URL.

Regarding the Python SDK, following will do the trick:

```
id = 23423423423
css = shopify.CustomerSavedSearch.find(id)
```